# Keeping passwords secure during transmission

Tags: security, hash, passwords, password-hash

In my web application, I'm implementing a blacklist of passwords that user's won't be able to select. As mentioned in Jeff's [God Login](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-god-login/) post, this is because some passwords are very commonly used and exist in [readily](https://xato.net/passwords/more-top-worst-passwords/) [available](http://wiki.skullsecurity.org/Passwords) [wordlists](https://crackstation.net/buy-crackstation-wordlist-password-cracking-dictionary.htm) used by brute forcing tools.

I had planned to store the blacklisted passwords in a database table (in the clear),  with an [MD5 hash of it as a Functional Index](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89127/optimise-huge-postgres-table-for-fast-read#comment159609_89135). So, when the query is sent to the server, it looks like this:

```
SELECT 1 
FROM blacklist AS a 
WHERE MD5(a.password) = 'MD5stringOfPasswordSubmitted';
```

I don't think the "in the clear" storage of these passwords is an issue since the passwords are *blacklisted*. No user can set it to one of these.. so who cares if passwords in *this table* are stored in the clear.

**But, is the transmission of this query *to the database server* a problem I should worry about?**

If my user is trying to set their password, at the moment the app will MD5 the password, send that to the database to query this blacklist table. If no result is returned, the app will allow them to have it as their password (as long as other validation requirements are also met).

Is this something I should worry about?

Could this be implemented another way so passwords users are trying to set *are* kept secure still? Is it really necessary to resort to storing a salted hash via Bcrypt (like is in my user table) even just for this blacklist usage? Would using a YAML file in the local directory structure of my app have any of this same risk?

The aim is to prevent users choosing a password that's common, and checking that in a very fast way (hence MD5) as part of the validation process.

Comment: Need any more help with this? If so I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how the transmission of the query could be a problem. If your web application does the MD5 encoding and an attacker intercepts the communication with the database, there is no way he can get back the user's password from it.

MD5 is not safe for storing passwords as attackers may be able to find passwords that result in the same hash value (collisions), but there is no way to convert a hash value back to the clear text from which it originated.

If you're worried about leaking other sensitive data when querying the database, you could consider encrypting the communication channel.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about the transmission of passwords since they are hashed using a one-way algorithm (as user18044 pointed out) however expanding more on the weaknesses of MD5 - I wouldn't use that algorithm at all especially if you aren't using a salt.  The reason why is because MD5 [rainbow tables](https://www.freerainbowtables.com/tables/) have been created for a very large set of possible combinations of passwords.  In fact it's very likely that the password lists that you are referring to have been generated after searching MD5 tables or using [online services](https://crackstation.net/) that will give you a password by submitting an MD5 hash (if the password has already been cracked previously or is in some table).  I would recommend using a salt or using another algorithm like SHA-256.  Security is my specialty and I have a rig that is capable of cracking MD5 hashes at hundreds of billions per second however if there is a salt involved it either slows me down or stops me all together (if the salt is not known).  That same rig can crack SHA-256 but it takes much longer for it to crack each one because SHA-256 iterates over itself enough times to make each iteration slow enough to make cracking less feasible.

As was already mentioned I would certainly use SSL either way to better protect all data that is transmitted.

Answer (score 0):

> But, is the transmission of this query to the database server a problem I should worry about?

This depends on your network topology. e.g.

- Is the database server on the same private local network? Then this is low risk.
- Is the database server on the same network, but shared with other machines and users. Then this is medium risk (you need to trust all the other machines and users).
- Is the database server across the internet? Then this is high risk.

Depending on your accepted risk level, you may want to protect the connection to the database with SSL/TLS.

Even though you are hashing with MD5, MD5 is considered a weak hashing algorithm so if a MITM grabs the password as it is queried on your database, they could run it through a tool such as [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) using a word list and intercept any password set by your users.

You could try and hash the password using another algorithm for this lookup - however this means implementing a "static salt" (called a pepper) on your system to avoid any hash comparisons of intercepted data. It may be much easier to simply connect with SSL/TLS to avoid this completely.

For storage of the password itself (once it has passed your check), definitely use a secure algorithm here such as bcrypt or scrypt.